# load .csv file with json data in bq table

Tags: json, csv

I have "{\"ex1\":\"somestuffhere\",\"ex2\":\"somestuffhere"\,"ex3\":\"somestuffhere\"}" this kind of data in one column of .csv file i want to load this .csv file in BQ table using load data statement. How  to load it? I have already added quote = '"' flag but it gives  error message: Data between close quote character (") and field separator.;

I have already added quote = '"' flag